# In Facebook, if I share some post from others timeline onto my timeline, who will be able to see it?

Tags: facebook

In Facebook, if I share some post from others timeline onto my timeline, who will be able to see it and where? Also who will be able to see it and where when I tag friends while sharing the post onto my timeline?

Answer (score 1):

You can always set the privacy.

**About Privacy**

> Once you tend to share a post it opens a popup in that we can have
>   options to add extra content(Optional) about the post and also we will have
>   privacy option to choose between `Public/Friends/Custom/Onlyme`

**Tagging Friends**

> You can tag your friends by clicking on image and by choosing Tag
>   option or simply you can tag your friends in the popup content by
>   calling them in this way `@yourfriendname`

Answer (score 0):

If your timeline is viewable by the public, this post will be viewable by the public. If it's only viewable by friends, it will be viewable by friends.

Answer (score 0):

From [Facebook help center](https://www.facebook.com/help/459934584025324/)

> If you want to change the audience of a post after you've shared it, click the audience selector and select a new audience. Remember, when you post to another person's Timeline, that person controls what audience can view the post. Additionally, anyone who gets tagged in a post may see it, along with their friends.